# If without else not running

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a little code for testing a sprite, that I want to move with the mouse. When I click the screen, the sprite has to move to the clicked point. But something weird is going on.

I'm running it in a thread, called Controls, that extends to Thread and implements MouseListener, and using the following code, the sprite moves.

```
public void run() {
    while(true){
        if((int)point.getX() > player.getX()){
            while((int)point.getX() > player.getX()){
                player.moveX(1);
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Nah!");
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected, but if i do this:

```
public void run() {
    while(true){
        if((int)point.getX() > player.getX()){
            while((int)point.getX() > player.getX()){
                player.moveX(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work. If i do this:

```
public void run() {
    while(true){
        if((int)point.getX() > player.getX()){
            while((int)point.getX() > player.getX()){
                player.moveX(1);
            }
        }
        else{

        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work either. I have no idea of what is going on, any ideas?

Comment: if always running. and always return false.

Comment: What does 'it doesn't work' mean?

Comment: @EvanKnowles What i mean is that the sprite doesn't move. And if i put something else, like a System.out.println("Yeah!"), it does not appear on the console, only if i put the Else with another System.out, the if works.

Comment: That `else` statement is not going to be making a difference - there's a difference in your starting state, or in some other code that's running. What else is supposed to modify `point.getX()`?

Comment: Why the down votes? OP tries some code and asks a question, that's not legitimate for people here?

Comment: @EvanKnowles I have a MouseListener, and the method MouseClicked is the one which is changing the point.getX(). And i'm with you with the else statement is not going to make a difference, but for some reason, without it.... the sprite refuses to move.

Comment: maybe you init your test with different data. try writing a unit test with stable input and you'll see `if` works as per spec - with or without `else`

Comment: Just a quick guess, but because of the If else you have given the time for the application so do some work and you can see the output as the window is drawn again

Comment: Yeah, I think @KennethClark is right. You're in an infinite loop and you're not giving it a chance to redraw, but there is time when you print the output.

Comment: Can you extend your code to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When you are running parallel code you shoud give other threads some time to do their work:

```
public void run() {
    while(true){
        if((int)point.getX() > player.getX()){
            while((int)point.getX() > player.getX()){
                player.moveX(1);
            }
        }
        sleep(20 /* ms */);
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha yup! This worked! You're right. Maybe because with the else{System.out.println()} i was giving it some time. Can it be?

Comment: This will work however your GUI will freeze, rather repaint the screen or use a timer

Comment: This will indeed "fix" the issue, but it's not a fix.

Comment: keep in mind this is just a quick-fix and should explain your misunderstanding: Not the "missing-else" is your problem it's a multithreading problem.

Comment: No, it's working fine, the player has a timer which paints everything. I already learned the hard way haha.

Comment: All right guys, apparently i found the solution. The point variable, which is a Point class, it's been changed by the mouse listener MouseClicked method, so i declared it Volatile, and it works without a problem.

TL;DR:
I declared the Point variable as volatile.

Comment: you might want to post it as a seperate answer